# eclipselink metamodel with gradle and groovy

Tags: java, jpa, gradle, eclipselink, build.gradle

How i can get generate metamodel classes from **org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor** in gradle?

In maven i use someone like

`<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>                 <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
             <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
              <compilerArg>-Aeclipselink.persistenceunits=unit-name
              </compilerArg>
          </compilerArgs> 
      </configuration>
 </plugin>`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late for you to be useful, but wanted to share how I solved the problem. The following will generate metamodel every time you compile. Note, if you remove the line with `delete`, the compiler will probably complain.

```
ext {
    metamodelPath="$buildDir/generated-sources/metamodel"
}
compileJava {

    doFirst {
        file(metamodelPath).delete()
        file(metamodelPath).mkdirs()
    }
    options.compilerArgs += ['-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml', '-s', metamodelPath ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the previous solution does not work for me. But it was a good starting point. The dependencies closure is missing.

This works under Gradle 5.6.1 and Groovy 2.5.4:

```
ext {
    eclipselink='2.7.3'
    metamodelPath="$buildDir/generated/sources/metamodel/java/main"
    persistenceXMLLocation="src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml"
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        file(metamodelPath).delete()
        file(metamodelPath).mkdirs()
    }
    options.compilerArgs += ["-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=${new File(project.projectDir, persistenceXMLLocation).absolutePath}", '-s', metamodelPath]
}

dependencies {
    api "org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:$eclipselink"
    annotationProcessor "org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:$eclipselink"
}
```